# Correct path to resources

Tags: php, codeigniter, path, smarty

I'm having trouble with the path when a file calls a css or a js file.

I'm using Codeigniter also Smarty template engine. My base URL is> http://local.project

My css and js files are located in> project/site/assets/css and project/site/assets/js

The thing is that when I call the resources from the view the path is a mess and not found error appears.

I have tried many ways but still can't make it. I begin to think that this can be a path problem from Codeigniter. I mean.. maybe I'm missing something that I can't figure what is.

When I do an inspection with the browser I can see that this is set by default>
http://local.project/

and then from the view I call it like>

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{site_url()}assets/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
```

but the path that is built is>

```
http://local.project/%7Bsite_url()%7Dassets/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.js 400 (Bad Request)
```

I'm driving crazy here, any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it. Just opened my Smarty.php file and changed this line view/admin just to views

```
        $this->setTemplateDir(APPPATH.'views');
```

After that the url I could use from the view is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **base_url()** instead of site_url().

try:

```
<?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='" . base_url() . "assets/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.js'></script>" ;
?>
```

Comment: You should do this

<?php
   echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='" . base_url() . "/assets/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.js'></script>" ;
?>

You just need to echo the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
```

can you provide your ip,to view the page?

Comment: Hi, non of those work :( this is one of the many errors> GET http://local.project/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.pie.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is there picture? try to get it's path (right-click on it) you will get a good idea on how you can link the js and css files..

Answer (score 0):

To use the base_url() you need to call in your controller the URL helper:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then in your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, not working either. This is one of the errors> GET http://local.project/%7Bbase_url()%7Dassets/js/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js 400 (Bad Request)

Answer (score 0):

First of all load the url helper

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

secondly get base address using this

```
echo base_url();
```

and finally your base address is "http://local.project", no slash at the end, so try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
```

and make sure your base address do not have any extra characters, like space or enter

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the url helper previously